# BufferedReader Class not working in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, mysql, servlets, bufferedreader

I want to access mysql database on my localhost via a java servlet through my android app. I was able to access database through a java class but when tried the same code in my android activity, it's not working. Below is the code for my java servlet, java class through which I successfully accessed my database and android code which isn't working. In my LogCat log I am getting all the logs till BufferedReader class. Also please tell me which widget can I use in Android to display the response string. I know presently my response string will contain HTML code but that doesn't matter I just want to know if I am able to access my database. Thank You.
Java Servlet Code:

```
package org.spark.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloServlet2
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet2")

public class HelloServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException, ServletException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello World2</h1>");
        // connecting to database
        Connection con = null;    
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con =DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "password");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("Use servlettest");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM servlet");
            // displaying records
            while(rs.next()){
                out.print(rs.getObject(1).toString());
                out.print("\t\t\t");
                out.print(rs.getObject(2).toString());
                out.print("<br>");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Servlet Could not display records.", e);
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
              throw new ServletException("JDBC Driver not found.", e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if(rs != null) {
                        rs.close();
                        rs = null;
                    }
                    if(stmt != null) {
                        stmt.close();
                        stmt = null;
                    }
                    if(con != null) {
                        con.close();
                        con = null;
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
            out.println("</body></html>");  
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Java Class Code:

```
package org.ProjectEuler;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class HelloServlet {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/HelloServlet/HelloServlet2");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( conn.getOutputStream()));
            out.write("username=javaworld\r\n");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream()));

            String response;
            while ( (response = in.readLine()) != null ) {
                System.out.println( response );
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch ( MalformedURLException ex ) {
            // a real program would need to handle this exception
        }
        catch ( IOException ex ) {
            // a real program would need to handle this exception
        }
    }
}
```

Andriod Code:

```
package org.spark.mysqltest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.*;


public class MySqlTestActivity extends Activity {
    EditText test;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("checked","checked");
        System.out.println("check");
        Log.d("checked2","checked2");
        test = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mtv);
        Log.d("checked3","checked3");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("checked4","checked4");

        try {
            Log.d("checked5","checked5");

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/HelloServlet/HelloServlet2");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            Log.d("checked6","checked6");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( conn.getOutputStream()));
            Log.d("checked7","checked7");
            out.write("username=javaworld\r\n");
            Log.d("checke","checke");
            out.flush();
            Log.d("check","check");
            out.close();
            Log.d("chec","chec");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream()));
            Log.d("che","che");
            String response;
            while ( (response = in.readLine()) != null ) {
                System.out.println( response );
              //  test.setText(response);
                Log.d("checked8","checked8");
            }
            Log.d("checked9","checked9");
            in.close();
        }
        catch ( MalformedURLException ex ) {
            // a real program would need to handle this exception
        }
        catch ( IOException ex ) {
            // a real program would need to handle this exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: you aren't specifying an encoding when you create your `InputStreamReader`. That means you'll use the platform default encoding, which may not be the encoding used to create the web response. (Likewise when you're creating the request.)

Second problem: you're *ignoring* any exceptions:

```
catch ( MalformedURLException ex ) {
    // a real program would need to handle this exception
}
catch ( IOException ex ) {
    // a real program would need to handle this exception
}
```

My guess is that an exception *is* being thrown, but you have no idea because you've swallowed those exceptions without even logging. At the very *least*, add logging in here and I think you'll see what's going wrong. You should almost *never* have empty catch statements like this.

Do you have any reason for using the low-level API like this, by the way? Using a good high-level HTTP client library is likely to make your life a *lot* simpler.